# Converting ETH from Ethereum Wallet to BNB on a (BSC) Wallet

Tags: ether, wallets, bsc, binance-smart-chain

How can I programmatically convert ETH from an Ethereum network wallet to BNB on a Binance Smart Chain (BSC) network wallet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some form of a "bridge" between different networks. Many services offer this functionality, some of which provide an API for your use.

For instance, take a look at https://docs.li.fi/